# How to write xpath for following example?

Tags: selenium, xpath

For example, I have div tag that has two attributes.
class='hello@123' text='321@he@321llo@321'

```
<div> class='hello@123' text='321@he@321llo@321'></div>
```

Here, I want to write xpath for both class and text attributes but numbers may change dynamically. ie., "hello@123" may become "345"  when we reload. "321@he@321llo@321"  may become "567@he@456llo@321".

Note: Need to write xpath in single line not separately.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the (corrected) two-attribute-HTML

```
<div class='hello@123' text='321@he@321llo@321'>...</div>
```

you can select it using the following, for example:

1. Using the `contains()` function

   ```
   //div[contains(@class,'hello') and contains(@text,'@he@')]
   ```

   This is quite specific and only applicable if the "hello" is always split in the same way
2. Using the `translate()` function to mask everything except the chars for "hello"

   ```
   //div[translate(@class,'@0123456789','')='hello' and translate(@text,'@0123456789','')='hello']
   ```

   This removes all `@` chars and digits and checks if the remaining string is "hello"

I guess combining these two approaches you will be able to create your own XPath expression fitting your needs. The patterns you provided were not fully clear, so this may only approach a good enough solution.